# I'm experiencing a segmentation fault, and not sure why

Tags: segmentation-fault

**This is where i'm calling the vertex class, overloading the << operator to print
out it's private member ID**

```
     case 'v':

     if (isAlreadyFile == true){

       vector <Vertex*> vertices = graph.GetVertices();
       cout << "Vertices: " << endl;

       int currentVerticie = 0;
       Vertex v = *vertices[currentVerticie];

       while (currentVerticie < numVertices){

         cout << v << endl;
         currentVerticie++;
         v = *vertices[currentVerticie];

       }

     }

     else{
```

**This is the Vertex class implementation file, please help!**

```
#include "Vertex.h"

using namespace std;

// Static Member Variables
int Vertex:: m_IDTotal = -1;

Vertex::Vertex(){

  m_IDTotal++;
  m_ID = m_IDTotal;

}

int Vertex::GetID() const {

  int ID = m_ID;
  return ID;

}

ostream& operator << (ostream &sout, const Vertex &v){

  sout << "  ID: " << v.GetID();

  return sout;

}
```

Comment: Step in with a debugger.  Right before the segfault, what are the values of all of the variables?

Comment: Try giving a SMALL but complete sample of code that exhibits your problem.  Since you don't know what the problem is, picking a few bits and posting them may exclude code that causes - or is part of - the problem.   Since you are working with a vector of pointers, odds are the setup of the pointers in the vector is the cause - and you have shown none of that.

Comment: All that vector of pointers looks suboptimal to me. As well as the dereferencing without checking if the vector had size > 0.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely numVertices has a bad value. change it to (int)vertices.size()